# Let $T:X \to Y$ be a surjective bounded linear operator. Then T satisfis: if U is an open set in X, then T(U) is an open set in Y.

Tags: general-topology, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let X and Y be Banach spaces. Let $T:X \to Y$ be a surjective bounded linear operator. Then T satisfis: 
   if U is an open set in X, then T(U) is an open set in Y.

My work: I think it suffices to show there exists $T^{-1}$ such that it is surjective, bounded and linear but I don't know under what conditions I can say there the inverse function exists. Also, I can't see how I can use the completeness of X and Y in this question.

Comment: It's well known https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(functional_analysis)

Answer (score 0):

That is called *The Open Mapping Theorem*. You can see this theorem in any(?) functional analysis textbook (It is not difficult to show this if you know the Baire Category Theorem).

From this fact, you can see *The inverse mapping theorem*, that is, if $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces and $T: X \rightarrow Y$ is a bounded linear operator that is bijective, then $T^{-1}$ is also bounded.